# Twitter Bootstrap: how to put unknown number of span* within a row-fluid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Assume I have the following nesting:

```
<div class="cointainer-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3">
         <!-- left sidebar here -->
      </div>
      <div class="span9">
         <!-- main content here -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to put an unknown number of `<div class="span3"></div>` in the main content area. (Each of the `span3` is suppose to contain a product photo, name, price, etc.) Of course, my aim is that be responsive. So, I might display 20 products, which I'd like to possibly display 5 products per "row" on a wide screen, then 4 products per "row" on a slightly less wide screen, then 3, then 2, then 1. For example (each X represents a product):

```
Wide Screen
row 1: X  X  X  X  X
row 2: X  X  X  X  X
row 3: X  X  X  X  X
row 4: X  X  X  X  X

Less Wide Screen
row 1: X  X  X  X
row 2: X  X  X  X
row 3: X  X  X  X
row 4: X  X  X  X
row 5: X  X  X  X

Even Less Wide Screen
row 1: X  X  X
row 2: X  X  X
row 3: X  X  X
row 4: X  X  X
row 5: X  X  X
row 6: X  X  X
row 7: X  X
```

It seems like I need to do nested rows. However, if I do that, then I'll only be able to fit a certain amount of products in each nested row. That'll cause problems as the screen width decreases, for example (each X represents a product):

```
Wide Screen
row 1: X  X  X  X  X
row 2: X  X  X  X  X
row 3: X  X  X  X  X

Less Wide Screen
row 1: X  X  X  X
       X
row 2: X  X  X  X
       X
row 3: X  X  X  X
       X
```

**How do I do what I want to do in Twitter Bootstrap?**

Comment: Although TWBS 3 will provide a more scalable grid across resolutions, the grid is meant to have a fixed number of columns. You should look at the [thumbnails](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) behavior.

Comment: But the `<li>` contains a `span*` which causes the same problems, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you not to use `.span*` classes for your purpose inside `.row-fluid` as the width for all blocks is defined in percents. So all `.span*` blocks will just change the width accordingly to the window size.

Just define your custom class e.g. `.product` with `float: left` and particular with and height:

```
.product{
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
}
```

and put all blocks inside one container without any rows. Browser will do the rest.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GmVJy/1/

Comment: So I'm not supposed to put my products in another `span*`? I thought it was the approach to take if I want to fully leverage TB. I see that your solution works, though. Just wondering if it's the TB way. Thoughts?

Comment: As i said there is a problem that all `.span*` blocks get responsive width inside a fluid row. But your product blocks should be fixed width to make it work. And actually these TB classes are used for aligning layout. So i guess it is not a TB way to use these styles for aligning products.